# JavaScript html data table issue

Tags: javascript

I have the following format for an html table (modified a bit to post here)...

```
<table class="table-style" id="tbl1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>SBU</th>
            <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
            <th>TY SLS</th>
            <th>TY BUD</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="parent" rowspan="14">test0</td>
            <td class="child" style="display: table-cell;">test1</td>
            <td class="child" style="display: table-cell;">106040943</td>
            <td class="child" style="display: table-cell;">117638617</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="child">test2</td>
            <td class="child">20733153</td>
            <td class="child">22164885</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="child">25 test3</td>
            <td class="child">49086765</td>
            <td class="child">53820000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="child">test4</td>
            <td class="child">30627906</td>
            <td class="child">34237662</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="parent" rowspan="8">test5</td>
            <td class="child">test6</td>
            <td class="child">120112816</td>
            <td class="child">126211000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="child">test7</td>
            <td class="child">66521923</td>
            <td class="child">78090000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using the following JavaScript to collapse rows that have the class of 'child' from the parent class...

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function () {

             function getChildren($row) {
                 var children = [];
                  while ($row.next().hasClass('child')){
                     children.push($row.next());
                     $row = $row.next();
                 }
                 return children;
             }

             $('.parent').on('click', function () {

                 var children = getChildren($(this));
                 $.each(children, function () {
                     $(this).toggle();
                 })
             });

         })
     </script>
```

However, it is only getting the first row...how can I get all rows to collapse until i reach the next parent class?

Comment: Are the `rowspan` values correct in your example HTML? It seems wrong. Could you correct?

Comment: they are correct actually, a separate script merges column 1

Comment: But the `rowspan=8` makes no sense, since there are only 2 rows to span in your example. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the actual `rowspan` values are not correct in your example (they have too large values), this could be a solution (I corrected those values in the sample table):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent').on('click', function () {
        var $row = $(this).parent();
        var rowspan = +$(this).attr('rowspan') || 1;
        $.merge($row, $row.nextAll()).slice(0, rowspan).find('.child').toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.table-style, th, td { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-style" id="tbl1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>SBU</th>
            <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
            <th>TY SLS</th>
            <th>TY BUD</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="parent" rowspan="4">test0</td>
            <td class="child" style="display: table-cell;">test1</td>
            <td class="child" style="display: table-cell;">106040943</td>
            <td class="child" style="display: table-cell;">117638617</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="child">test2</td>
            <td class="child">20733153</td>
            <td class="child">22164885</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="child">25 test3</td>
            <td class="child">49086765</td>
            <td class="child">53820000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="child">test4</td>
            <td class="child">30627906</td>
            <td class="child">34237662</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="parent" rowspan="2">test5</td>
            <td class="child">test6</td>
            <td class="child">120112816</td>
            <td class="child">126211000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="child">test7</td>
            <td class="child">66521923</td>
            <td class="child">78090000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: perfect!! that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery nextUntil() function. Pass in the `parent` class and you'll get the results you're looking for.

https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: i think this is what I am looking for, struggling a bit right now to implement it into what I currently have in the above JavaScript

Comment: Your table structure is a bit off. Take a look at this...

https://jsfiddle.net/wfcttnyL/